# Receive messages from Telegram Bot to Google App Engine via Cloud Endpoint

Tags: python, google-app-engine, telegram-bot

I have a python Google App Engine application that receive incoming message from Telegram Bot via webhook. I'm using Cloud Endpoint to receive request, so I use the Google Protocol RPC to manage the request and the response.

The json incoming update from Telegram that contain the message have a field called **`from`**. The problem is that when I write the RPC class to handle the message I can't use the name **`from`** for the variable because is a reserved keyword:

```
class TelegramMessage(messages.Message):
    message_id = messages.IntegerField(1, required = True)
    from = messages.MessageField(User, 2)
```

I can't change the name of variable because otherwise the **`from`** field from the incoming json go lost and I recive this warning in the console: No variant found for unrecognized field: from.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a python library like [python-telegram-bot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-telegram-bot). The author of the library [renamed](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/message.py#L33) the Python-incompatible `from` attribute to from_user. So just do:

```
user = bot.getUpdates()[-1].from_user
```